# Можно ли построить словосочетание: В ЗАТОЧЕНИИ МОЕЙ ЛЮБВИ?

Tags: грамотная-речь, семантика

В заточении моей любви.  Если подобное написание и является правильным, то почему?

Answer (score 2):

ЗАТОЧИТЬ, кого (что). Книжн. Подвергнуть заключению, лишить свободы. З. в тюрьму, в крепость. З. в одиночной камере. З. в монастырь. Заточение; заточенье.

Странное словосочетание. Обычно можно заточить кого-то, например "заточение патриарха и Годуновых". В переносном смысле можно заточить любовь, то есть скрыть ее, лишить  свободы, тогда получим "заточение/сокрытие моей любви". Теперь надо перейти к П.п. (в чем) - в заточении. Например: кто заинтересован в заточении моей любви?

Поэтому сочетание необычное, но в принципе возможное.

Answer (score 2):

Приемлемое сочетание, ибо нахождение в **заточении** - это не только лишение свободы на физическом плане, но и определённое душевное состояние - состояние **скованности**. Любовь - очень мощное чувство, и она вполне может **сковать** эмоции и **заключить** мысли, при этом  можно сделаться **узником** любви, а **узник** и есть тот, кто находится в **заточении**.

Comment: Если любовь - этот тюремщик, то, боюсь, это выражение НЕВЕРНО. К примеру, узник совести — человек, физическая свобода которого ограничена тюремным заключением или иным способом из-за его политических, религиозных или иных убеждений. По аналогии узник (какой) любви - человек, находящийся под сильным влиянием этого чувства. (Это определение, а не дополнение.) А вот заключение (чего) любви - это именно дополнение. В этом случае под стражей держат любовь, а не любовь держит бедного узника.

Comment: Можно быть узником в тюрьме, а не у тюремщика, ибо тюремщик осуществляет надзор и охрану. Поэтому любовь в данном контексте - это тюрьма, но не тюремщик.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы уточнил. Кто именно находится "в заточении"?
Фразы "я в заточении моей любви" и "она в заточении моей любви" будут иметь **очень** различное значение. И если в первом случае человеку можно позавидовать, то во втором - следует посочувствовать обоим.

Comment: Дело не совсем в значении. Эта фраза не из текста, вопрос лишь в том, будет ли она правильной, при ИМЕННО таком написании.

Answer (score 1):

Может ли В ЗАТОЧЕНИИ управлять словом ЛЮБВИ?

Заточить (подвергнуть заточению) ***кого-л. куда и где***. 1. куда (направление
действия). Заточить в монастырь. Ее везде разыскивали жандармы, чтобы заточить в
тюрьму или казнить (Морозов). 2. где (место действия, при наличии уточняющего об-
стоятельства). Заточить в тюрьме в одиночную камеру. [Здесь](http://www.interword.se/Syntax/Lektionsmaterial/Rozenthal_Rektion.pdf)

В заточении любви - метафора хоть и красивая, но, с точки зрения грамматики, неправильная. Слово ЗАТОЧИТЬ (заточение) не употребляется с существительными в Р.п.

**Спасибо за вопрос! Пять баллов!**

Comment: Большое спасибо, меня как раз интересовало это словосочетание с позиции допустимых норм.

Comment: Никого не слушайте, уважаемый Stanlie_Trout, это выражение - продукт вашего индивидуального творчества, не бойтесь эксперементировать! Многие известные люди: Пушкин, Есенин, МАяковский и т.д. - создавали не то что словосочетания, но и новые слова, в угоду лишь своей Музе, но никак не знатокам грамматики, от того их творчество и выглядит таким ярким, таким непостижимым и великим!

Comment: О ГРАММАТИКЕ. Р.п. сущ. может быть объектным или признаковым, например: улыбка (кого) ребенка - улыбка (какая) счастья. Вся НЕПРАВИЛЬНОСТЬ грамматики для сущ. "заточение" заключается в том, что ОТГЛАГОЛЬНЫМ существительным  признаковая функция  НЕ СВОЙСТВЕННА, но всё-таки она категорически не запрещена. Поэтому в качестве смелого эксперимента можно представить следующий текст: "Я постоянно нахожусь в заточении любви, или я нахожусь в заточении гнева, или в заточении печали. Я никогда не бываю свободен, я вечный узник своих чувств". Здесь признаковое значение сущ. узнается по тематике текста.

Comment: Мне кажется, лучше "в заточении у любви".

Comment: Значительно лучше и понятнее, но здесь спор идет о беспредложном Р.п. (в заточении любви - в любовном заточении).

Answer (score 0):

***Ответ справочной службы " Грамма.ру".***

Выражение ***"в заточении моей любви"*** не кажется нам корректным. Существительное "заточение" в современном русском литературном языке используется в следующих значениях: 1) Действие по глаголу заточить - заточать (подвергнуть заключению: в тюрьму, в монастырь и т.п.); 2) Пребывание в тюрьме, в ссылке. Теоретически, конечно, возможен контекст с относительно корректным употреблением этого существительного в первом значении: типа "в заточении моей любви в самые глубины моего сердца виновато провидение"...

Comment: Что касается моего личного мнения, то, пожалуй, соглашусь с Софией: "...в заточении любви". В словосочетании "в заточении моей любви", как верно отметила София, "любовь держат под стражей, а НЕ любовь держит под стражей".